# Xamarin Forms, MVVM Light и ListView ContextActions

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm-light

Коллеги, привет.

Возникла проблема с реализацией удаления из ListView с помощью кнопки в Context Action. Мой код:

View:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView
        x:Name="JobsList"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveJobCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=JobsList}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            IsDestructive="True"
                            Text="Удалить" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DetailJobCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=TaskList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" Text="Добавить" />
</StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        if (navigationService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("navigationService");
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        Jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
        RemoveJobCommand = new Command(Remove);
        DetailJobCommand = new Command(Detail);
        NavigateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            _navigationService.NavigateTo(Pages.AddJobPage);
        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Job>(this, "AddNew", (job) =>
        {
            Jobs.Add(job);
        });
        //Jobs.Add(new Job() { Name = "Test", Description = "Test desc" });
    }

    private void Detail(object obj)
    {
        Job job = obj as Job;
        obj = null;
        if (job == null) return;
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(Pages.DetailsJobPage, job);
    }

    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    /// Logic ///

    public ObservableCollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public ICommand RemoveJobCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand DetailJobCommand { get; set; }

    private void Remove(object obj)
    {
        Job job = obj as Job;
        obj = null;
        if (job == null) return;
        Jobs.Remove(job);
    }
}
```

Я добавляю новые таски в список и затем их удаляю без проблем. Если я зайду в один из тасков и потом вернусь обратно к списку, то удаление перестает работать.

Проблема заключается в том, что при попытке удалить мне в метод Remove передается неверное значение таска. Обычно это предыдущий удаленный таск:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно в коллекции его уже нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно реализовать передачу верного таска для удаления?

Comment: хм... проблема воспроизводится только на UWP. На Android удаление происходит корректно.